# Counting 3 Level Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

im trying to figure out how to Count all Items from child to child where a column called "IsVerified" is true. I got the first two childs counted (BlogPost -> Comments(child) -> SubComments(child)) but i cant figure out how to count the third child

The structure of the model is similar to this on 
BlogPost -> Comments -> SubComments -> SubSubComments

I cant show you the real models so here is an example:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c357bfdd158cc6a392d9

Its all working instead of the third child.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
// Don't need ToList here, lazy is fine
var blogs = db.BlogPosts.Include("Comments.SubComments.SubSubComments");

var count = blogs.SelectMany(b => b.Comments)
                 .Where(c => c.IsVerified)
                 .SelectMany(c => c.SubComments)
                 .Where(sc => sc.IsVerifier)
                 .Count();
```

will get the count of verified sub-comments in verified sub-comments.

And because I've not used `ToList` on the initial expression this should all be converted to SQL and executed on the server (details of the SQL will depend on the details of the model, for example whether relationships are required or not).